# cPanel Password Protect Folders - Possible to Track Access?

Tags: php, cpanel

If I've used cPanel to password protect a page, is there any way to retrieve the authorized user's name/id when they access the folder (or page?).

For a temporary client review I'd like to customize a password protected page based on their login credentials and don't know how to determine the user id/name when they log in as a cPanel authorized user. Is an event generated that I can listen for on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is using HTTP auth, you can not get it with JavaScript. You'd need to use a server side language to pass it to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is it possible to retrieve those details via PHP then? Or do I need to create my own PHP login page?

Comment: Great - can you point me in the right direction for a sample PHP file that gives an example of how to accomplish this? I'm having trouble finding anything, realize this is probably a basic question.

Comment: Never mind - found it here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.